# iOS : How to make a CGRect as visible rect for UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview

I am drawing a line graph in UIView for the width of 1200pixels. But I can visible only up to 320pixels. How can I make a rectangle starting from x=880 and width = 320 as visible?.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is bloody mess. Try get yourself more clear. Maybe, provide some screenshots. Or code.

Comment: using an instance of `UIScrollView`, maybe? then you could set the `contentOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw graph at 880px using following way.

**Step 1** : Take `UIScrollView` with `width = 1200`.

**Step 2** : Add `UIView` in `UIScrollView` having X position = 880 and width = 320;

now you can draw graph on `UIView`. you received output same as you want.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not clear, but I guess that your problem is how to fully visualize a view that is clipped by the limit of the screen size.
There is a property on `UIView` to do that and is called `-transform`, using that you can scale your view until it fits, but pointing the usability factor I think that it would be useless.
There is a special view called `UIScrollView`, its purpouse is to display bigger views and navigate them by panning whith your fingers or zoom in/out just using a pich gesture.
I this way you can make the user explore your graph data.